# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty on PHP8

Tags: php, fatal-error, php-8, gravityforms

This code is attached to a Gravity form, there is a file upload field on the form, and this code (although poorly written) grabs each file from the file upload field and uploads it to the server. My problem is, now that we have upgraded to PHP8, it's throwing an error:

```
//$entry[35] is the file upload field in the form. 

//This grabs the uploaded file whatever it may be, and uploads it to the server
$newest_again = str_replace('[',"",$entry[35]);
$newest_final = str_replace(']',"",$newest_again);
$newest_fin   = str_replace('"',"",$newest_final);

$entryArr = explode(",",$newest_fin);

if(!empty($entry[35])){
    if(count($entryArr) > 1){
        //multiple files have been added to the upload field
        $count   = 0;
        $token   = "";
        $fileArr = array();
        $binArr  = array();
        $extens  = array();

        foreach($entryArr as $file_entry){
            //processing string to grab the file name only for each file
            $new = str_replace('\\',"",$file_entry);
            $new_again = str_replace('[',"",$new);
            $new_final = str_replace(']',"",$new_again);
            $new_fin   = str_replace('"',"",$new_final);
            $binFile   = file_get_contents($new_fin);
            $ext       = pathinfo($new_fin, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            array_push($fileArr, $new_fin);
            array_push($binArr, $binFile);
            array_push($extens, $ext);
        }

        //upload each file to server

        while($count < (count($fileArr))){

            $upload = curlUpload("/uploads.json", $binArr[$count], 'screenshot-'.$count.".".$extens[$count], $fileArr[$count],$token);  // Attachments will have the prettyname screenshot.[$ext]
            if($token == ""){
                $token = $upload->upload->token;
            }
            else{
                $token = $token;
            }

            $count ++;
        }

        print_r($uploads);

    }
    else{
        //just one file was added to the form, so upload it
        $fileArr = array();
        $placeholder ="";
        $new = str_replace('\\',"",$entry[35]);
        $new_again = str_replace('[',"",$new);
        $new_final = str_replace(']',"",$new_again);
        $new_fin   = str_replace('"',"",$new_final);
        $binaryFile = file_get_contents($new_fin);
        $ext = pathinfo($new_fin, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  // Upload field ID
        $upload = curlUpload("/uploads.json", $binaryFile, 'screenshot.'.$ext, $new_fin, $placeholder);  // Attachments will have the prettyname screenshot.[$ext]
        $token = $upload->upload->token;

    }
}
```

The error is:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /wp-content/themes/blankslate/functions.php:31483
```

Stack:

```
 #0 /wp-content/themes/blankslate/functions.php(31483): file_get_contents('')
```

This error is ONLY thrown if a file is not added to the upload field on the form. If a file or files are added, the error is not thrown. It seems to be calling file_get_contents(); and throwing the error message when nothing has been added to the upload field in the form. This is the line that is throwing the error message:

```
 $binFile   = file_get_contents($new_fin);
```

I wrapped everything in this block:

```
 if(!empty($entry[35])){
```

So that this code ONLY runs if the file upload field is not empty, but it is still throwing the error message even when no files are added to the file upload field in the form.

Is there anything I can add to this code that will prevent the error?

Comment: The error message gives you the line number where the problem occurred. Which line of the code you have posted is line 31483?

Comment: This line:  $binFile   = file_get_contents($new_fin);

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error? I am running into the same issue. It looks like this is a similar issue on 8.1.6. 
https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket/issues/3422